# Unary negation ignored in user input in my pemdas calculator using python

Tags: python, calculator, postfix-notation, shunting-yard

I'm having issues with my PEMDAS calculator built in python. The issue that I'm encountering is mainly that I can't find a way to make my code recognize the "-" sign at the beginning of the user's input. So when a user submits an input like -5+5 , the code will completely dismiss the block in charge of handling cases in which there exist unary negation and simply perform a normal addition.

Which ends up in an incorrect output of -10, instead of Adding -5 to positive 5, which should give 0 as output

Here is my code:

```py
import re
import math
import tkinter as tk

PEMDAS = {'+': 4, '-': 4, '*': 5, '/': 5, '%': 9, '√': 7, "^": 8, '(': 1, ')': 1, "[": 2, "]": 2, "{": 3, "}": 3}


def is_valid_expression(expression):
    return re.match(r'^[-^+*/()%.√\d\s\[\]{}]+$', expression) or re.match(r'^\d+%\s*$', expression)

def tokenize(expression):
    separated_expression = ""

    if expression.startswith("-"):
        valid_components = ["-1"] + re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+|\.\d+|%|\D)|[-+\*/\(\)\^]+', expression[1:])
        return valid_components
    elif "." not in expression:
        separated_expression = expression.replace(" ", "")
        valid_components = re.findall(r'(\d+|\+|-|\*|/|\(|\)|\[|\]|\{|\^|√|%)', separated_expression)
        return valid_components
    elif "." in expression and " " in expression:
        separated_expression = expression.replace(" ", "")
        valid_components = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+|%|\D)|[-+\*/\(\)\^]+', separated_expression)
        return valid_components
    elif "." in expression and " " not in expression:
        valid_components = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+|\.\d+|%|\D)|[-+\*/\(\)\^]+', expression)
        return valid_components


def shunting_yard(tokens):
    operators = []  # stack that will hold operators as they are processed
    output = []  # list that will hold the postfix expression.

    # iterates through each token
    for token in tokens:
        # if the token is an operator
        if token in '+-*/^√%':
            # it checks the precedence of each operator using the PEMDAS dictionary
            # and compares it to the precedence of operators in the operators stack.
            while operators and operators[-1] in '+-*/√%' and PEMDAS[token] <= PEMDAS[operators[-1]]:
                output.append(operators.pop())  # It pops operators from the stack and appends them to
                # the output list until the conditions for precedence are satisfied,

            operators.append(token)  # then it pushes the current token onto the operators stack.
        elif token in '([{':
            # If the token is an opening parenthesis, square bracket, or curly brace
            operators.append(token)  # it's pushed into the operators stack.
        elif token in ')]}':
            # If the token is a closing parenthesis, square bracket, or curly brace,
            # it pops operators from the operators stack and appends them to the output
            # list until a matching opening parenthesis, square bracket, or curly brace is encountered.
            while operators and operators[-1] not in '([{':
                output.append(operators.pop())
            if operators and operators[-1] in '([{':
                operators.pop()  # Remove the matching opening parenthesis, square bracket, or curly brace
            else:
                raise ValueError("Mismatched parentheses, brackets, or braces")
        else:
            # if it's not an operator or parenthesis, it's an operand, so it's appended to the output list.
            output.append(token)

    # After processing all tokens,
    # any remaining operators in the operators stack are popped and appended to
    # the output list to complete the conversion.
    while operators:
        output.append(operators.pop())
    return output



class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Calculator")
        #priority from each operator including parenthesis and brackets and % operator
        # Create an entry widget to display and input expressions
        self.expression_entry = tk.Entry(root, justify='right', font=('Arial', 22))
        self.expression_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=10, pady=10)


        #list of tuples named buttons is defined. 
        # Each tuple contains the text to be displayed on the button, 
        # and its row and column position in the grid layout. #setting up the color as well
        buttons = [
            ('7', 1, 0, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('8', 1, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('9', 1, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('/', 1, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
            ('4', 2, 0, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('5', 2, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('6', 2, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('*', 2, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
            ('1', 3, 0, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('2', 3, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('3', 3, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('-', 3, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
            ('0', 4, 0, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('.', 4, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), (']', 4, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('+', 4, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
            ('(', 5, 0, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), (')', 5, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('[', 5, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('%', 5, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
            ('{', 6, 0, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('}', 6, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('√', 6, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'black'), ('^', 6, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
            ('C', 7, 1, '#CCCCCC', 'red'), ('←', 7, 2, '#CCCCCC', 'red'), ("=", 7, 3, '#CCCCCC', 'black'),
        ]

        for (text, row, col, bg_color, fg_color) in buttons:
            button = tk.Button(root, text=text, font=('Arial', 16), width=5, height=2, bg=bg_color, fg=fg_color, command=lambda t=text: self.button_click(t))
            button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=5, pady=5)       

    def button_click(self, char):
        # try:
            if char == '=': #If the clicked button is '=', it signifies the user wants to evaluate the expression:
                expression = self.expression_entry.get() #It gets the expression from the expression_entry widget.

                #It checks if the expression ends with a number followed by '%' (e.g., "50%"). 
                # If so, it removes the '%' and adds division by 100 to handle percentages.
                if re.match(r'^\d+%\s*$', expression): #
                    expression = expression[:-1]  # Remove the %
                    expression = f"{expression} / 100"  # Add division by 100


                if is_valid_expression(expression): #It checks if the expression is valid using the is_valid_expression method.
                    tokens = tokenize(expression) #Tokenizes the expression
                    postfix = shunting_yard(tokens) #converts tokenized expression into postfix notation
                    evaluation = self.evaluate_postfix(postfix) #evaluates postfix converted expression
                    # updates the result in the expression_entry widget.
                    self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                    self.expression_entry.insert(0, str(evaluation))
                else:
                    #If invalid, it shows "Invalid Input".
                    self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                    self.expression_entry.insert(0, "Invalid Input")
        #If the clicked button is 'C', it clears the contents of the expression_entry widget.        
            elif char == 'C':
                self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            #If the clicked button is '←', 
            #it removes the last character from the text in the expression_entry widget.
            elif char == '←':
                current_text = self.expression_entry.get()
                self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.expression_entry.insert(0, current_text[:-1])
            #appends symbols depending on EACH OPERATOR INTRODUCED BY THE USER.
            elif char == '^':
                self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, '^')
            elif char == '√':
                self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, '√')
            elif char in '+-':
                if self.expression_entry.get():
                    last_char = self.expression_entry.get()[-1]
                    if last_char in '*/':
                        self.expression_entry.delete(len(self.expression_entry.get()) - 1, tk.END)
                        self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, f' {last_char} {char} ')
                    elif last_char == '-':
                        # Check if the previous character is also a '-'
                        # If yes, treat the current '-' as a unary negation
                        self.expression_entry.delete(len(self.expression_entry.get()) - 1, tk.END)
                        self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, ' -1 ')
                    else:
                        self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, char)
                else:  # Handle unary negation at the start of expression
                    self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, char)  # This is the part to add
            elif char in '*/%':
                if self.expression_entry.get():
                    last_char = self.expression_entry.get()[-1]
                    if last_char in '+-':
                        self.expression_entry.delete(len(self.expression_entry.get()) - 1, tk.END)
                        self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, f' {last_char} {char} ')
                    else:
                        self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, char)
            else:
                self.expression_entry.insert(tk.END, char)
        # except(IndexError, ValueError):
        #     self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        #     self.expression_entry.insert(0, "Syntax Error")

    def evaluate_postfix(self, tokens):
        stack = []

        for token in tokens:
            if token in '+-*/^√%':
                if token == '-':
                    if not stack or stack[-1] in '({[':
                        stack.append("-1")  # Push the -1 token as a marker for unary 
                    else:
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a - b))
                elif token == '+':
                    if stack and stack[-1] == '-1' or stack and stack[-2] == '-2':
                        stack.pop()
                        operand = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(-operand))
                    elif stack and stack[-1] == '%':
                        stack.pop()
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a + (a * b * 0.01)))
                    else:
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a + b))
                elif token == '*':
                    if stack and stack[-1] == '%':
                        stack.pop()
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a * (b * 0.01)))
                    else:
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a * b))
                elif token == '/':
                    if stack and stack[-1] == '%':
                        stack.pop()
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a / (b * 0.01)))
                    else:
                        b = float(stack.pop())
                        a = float(stack.pop())
                        stack.append(str(a / b))
                elif token == '^':
                    if stack and stack[-1] == '%':
                        stack.pop()  # Remove the %
                        b = 0.01  # Convert percentage to fraction
                    else:
                        b = 1.0  # No percentage, use 1.0 as multiplier

                    b_exponent = float(stack.pop())  # The exponent
                    a_base = float(stack.pop())  # The base
                    result = a_base ** b_exponent * b
                    stack.append(str(result))

                elif token == '√':
                    if stack and stack[-1] == '%':
                        stack.pop()  # Remove the %
                        b = 0.01  # Convert percentage to fraction
                    else:
                        b = 1.0  # No percentage, use 1.0 as multiplier

                    a = float(stack.pop())
                    result = math.sqrt(a) * b
                    stack.append(str(result))

                elif token == '%':
                    stack.append(token)
            elif token == '-1':
                if stack:
                    operand = float(stack.pop())
                    stack.append(str(-operand))  # Apply unary negation to the operand
                else:
                    stack.append(token)
            else:
                stack.append(token)

        result = self.evaluate_grouped_parentheses(stack)
        return result




    def evaluate_grouped_parentheses(self, tokens):
        stack = []
        current_group_value = 1.0
        current_group_operator = None
        unary_negation = False  # Flag to track unary negation

        for token in tokens:
            if token in '({[':
                # Start of a new parentheses group
                if current_group_operator:
                    raise ValueError("Consecutive group operators are not allowed")
                current_group_operator = token
                stack.append(token)
            elif token in ')}]':
                # End of a parentheses group, evaluate the group
                if not current_group_operator:
                    raise ValueError("Unmatched closing group operator")
                if current_group_operator == '{' and token == '}':
                    # Evaluate the contents of the curly braces group
                    group_contents = stack.pop()  # Get the contents of the curly braces 
                    group_tokens = tokenize(group_contents)  # Tokenize the contents
                    group_postfix = shunting_yard(group_tokens)  # Convert to postfix 
                    group_result = self.evaluate_postfix(group_postfix)  # Evaluate the 
                    stack.append(str(group_result))  # Replace the group contents with the 
                elif current_group_operator == '[' and token == ']':
                    # Evaluate the contents of the square brackets group
                    group_contents = stack.pop()  # Get the contents of the square brackets 
                    group_tokens = tokenize(group_contents)  # Tokenize the contents
                    group_postfix = shunting_yard(group_tokens)  # Convert to postfix 
                    group_result = self.evaluate_postfix(group_postfix)  # Evaluate the 
                    stack.append(str(group_result))  # Replace the group contents with the 
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Mismatched group operators")
                current_group_operator = None
            else:
                if current_group_operator:
                    stack.append(token)
                else:
                    if unary_negation:
                        unary_negation = False
                        stack.append(str(-float(token)))
                    else:
                        stack.append(token)

        # Calculate the result by multiplying numeric values left in the stack
        numeric_values = [float(value) for value in stack if value not in '({[}])']
        result = 1.0
        for value in numeric_values:
            result *= value

        return result * current_group_value





def main():
        root = tk.Tk()
        calculator = Calculator(root)
        root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I suggest to constrain your issue to a MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example No one's going to work through all that code to try to figure out what you're doing wrong

Comment: About half the code is need for a Minimum Reproducible Example. The Calculator class could be dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add code to treat unary operators separately to binary operators. '-' is especially tricky as it can either be a unary or binary operator, working out which is context dependant.

Let `P` represents prefix sequence, either a simple number like 5, or prefix expression like -5 or √9, or bracketed expressions (3+4) or even cases with multiple prefix operators -√9.

Your expression then has the form `P` or `P op P` or `P op P op P` etc., where `op` is a binary operator. This allows for expressions like `4 * -5`.

The key part here is the first thing you will encounter is a prefix sequence. So the main loop needs to be like

```
def E:
  while more_tokens
    P() // read a prefix sequence

    if next_token in '+-*/%': // just binary ops
       process_binary_operator
    else if token is EOF or closing bracket
       return
    else
       error

def P:
    while next_token in '-√': // prefix ops
       process_unary_op
    if next_token in '([{':
       E() // call main E function recursively 
       check next_token is matching closing brace
    else if next_token is digit
       output.append(token)
```

I've followed the shunting yard algorithm by Theodore Norvell at [https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm](https://www.engr.mun.ca/%7Etheo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight, this solution worked for me and now my code is able to recognize unary negation operations, but there is still a little issue, and it is that when it recognizes 2 different negative numbers, it multiplies them by each other, instead of solving it by subtracting them.

Therefore, if I submit -5-5

The output would be -5 multiplied by -5. Which is 25. This answer is incorrect. Is there a way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find a way to make my code recognize the "-" sign at the
> beginning of the user's input. So when a user submits an input like
> -5+5

You're missing `eval`

In `button_click()` function.

Remove  inside `if/else` nesting.

```
def button_click(self, char):
    # try:
        if char == '=': #If the clicked button is '=', it signifies the user wants to evaluate the expression:
            expression = self.expression_entry.get() #It gets the expression from the expression_entry widget.

            #It checks if the expression ends with a number followed by '%' (e.g., "50%"). 
            # If so, it removes the '%' and adds division by 100 to handle percentages.
            if re.match(r'^\d+%\s*$', expression): #
                expression = expression[:-1]  # Remove the %
                expression = f"{expression} / 100"  # Add division by 100


            if is_valid_expression(expression): #It checks if the expression is valid using the is_valid_expression method.
                tokens = tokenize(expression) #Tokenizes the expression
                postfix = shunting_yard(tokens) #converts tokenized expression into postfix notation
                evaluation = self.evaluate_postfix(postfix) #evaluates postfix converted expression
                # updates the result in the expression_entry widget.
                self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.expression_entry.insert(0, str(evaluation))
            else:
                #If invalid, it shows "Invalid Input".
                self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
                self.expression_entry.insert(0, "Invalid Input")
    #If the clicked button is 'C', it clears the contents of the
```

To:

```
def button_click(self, char):
    # try:
        if char == '=': #If the clicked button is '=', it signifies the user wants to evaluate the expression:
            expression = eval(self.expression_entry.get()) #It gets the expression from the expression_entry widget.
            print(expression)

            
            self.expression_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.expression_entry.insert(0, expression)
            
    #If the clicked button is 'C', it clears the contents of the expression_entry widget.
```

Edit:

Screenshot:

[image]